# Extend bivariate to multivariate convolution formula?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, convolution

In reference to this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21549/how-to-add-two-dependent-random-variables), the pdf for dependent random variables $X_1+X_2$ is given by:

$$f_{X_1+X_2}(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X_1,X_2}(x,z-x) \mathrm dx$$

How does this formula extend to the multivariate case $X_1+...+X_n$?

Comment: What did you try to pass from 2 to 3 random variables?